# Git server/client setup over LAN

Tags: git

I am new to Git. Please explain how to setup Git server and do push/pull from client machine. I am using Eclipse Git for client side.

Comment: You're member of this site for more than a year and should have realized by now that request for step-by-step tutorials are not considered good questions. Being new to a technology is no excuse for not even trying yourself and asking a specific question if you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The git is installed with the following command

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Every git user should first introduce himself to git

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

The above is already sufficient to use git in a distributed and secure way, provided users have access to the machine assuming the server role via SSH. On the server machine, creating a new repository can be done with

```
git init --bare /path/to/repository
```

Any client with ssh access to the machine can from then on clone the repository with

```
git clone username@hostname:/path/to/repository
```

Once cloned to the client's machine, the client can edit files, then commit and share them with:

```
cd /path/to/repository
#(edit some files)
git commit -a # Commit all changes to the local version of the repository
git push origin master # Push changes to the server's version of the repository
```

reference [GIT](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html)

Comment: did you configure the GIT Server yet?